# How To Sum with Foreach php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem to sum the values ​​using foreach.
[image]

I want to add the value of 12000 to 11000 but the result is only 11000, which is the last data.

```php
$no = 1;
foreach ($record->result_array() as $calc) {
    $sum = 0;
    $sum += $calc['harga_jual'] - $calc['diskon'];
    $no++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question ? (At a minimum, you should add some code that could be reproduced, not an image and this little sample of code, if you want to have a chance that someone helps you)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Answer (score 3):

The initialization of variable $sum ...is meant to be outside the foreach loop ...

That is $sum = 0  is meant to be outside the foreach loop ...

Answer (score 1):

**Note:-** The declaration & initialization of `$sum = 0;` is outside the foreach loop.

```
<?php 
    
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($record->result_array() as $calc) 
    {
       $sum += $calc['harga_jual'] - $calc['diskon'];
    }
    echo $sum;
    ?>
```